# Grouping irregular time series data by sentinel event

Tags: r, time-series, outliers

I have a df of hundreds of patients and a lab value measured at various dates. The labs were drawn at irregular time intervals. I am interested in seeing if this value rises to a critical point (example-1.5x the baseline of prior values), and need to mark this as an event. If lab values are taken within 7 days of each other I need these entries grouped together as an "episode", and if an event occurs within the episode, the entire episode should be flagged. Among flagged episodes I need to mark when the value is above 1.2x its baseline, when the value rises/falls to 1.2x baseline this will be used to mark the true start/end time of the event. If two episodes happen within 7 days of each other I would need to mark all values in and between the two episodes as a single episode. My end goal is to count the number of "episodes" per person and eventually exclude the values within the episode for later analysis.

I am able to use dplyr/mutate to make a new column to flag the individual sentinel events, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to group the rows into  7-day episodes.

Any help would be appreciated!

example dput df

```
structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3
), lab = c(0.9, 1.2, 1.4, 1, 1, 1.4, 1.6, 1.9, 1.5, 1.4, 1.4, 
1.6, 1.8, 1.5, 1.3, 1.3, 1, 1, 1.7, 1.4, 1.4, 1.6), date = structure(c(13375, 
13378, 13380, 13382, 13386, 16559, 16630, 16633, 16648, 17065, 
17070, 17091, 17093, 17096, 17172, 17225, 17871, 18033, 18158, 
18162, 18278, 18635), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -22L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Some of the example data got cut off during the copy-paste process. It's more likely that your question gets an answer if it includes a working data sample.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, should be fixed now

Comment: Yours is a challenging question, with complex definitions of *episode*, *baseline* and *event*. You should consider providing the expected output for the example data (and given the complexity, more examples). Think of those as unit tests to evaluate proposed solutions on.

Answer (score 0):

Only a partial answer because your problem is really complex. I'll explain how to group your dates into "episodes". My suggested approach is to use hierarchical clustering. With the method "complete" and cutoff set to 7, all the dates within an episode are within a 7-day radius. If, instead, you want an episode to include all dates having a distance less than 7 days with at least one member of the same cluster, you should consider "single" linkage method.

```r
df |>
  group_by(ID) |>
  mutate(event = lab > lab[1] * 1.5) |>
  mutate(episode = {
    dist(date) |>
      hclust(method = "complete") |>
      cutree(h = 7)
  }) |>
  group_by(ID, episode) |>
  mutate(flag = any(event)) |>
  as.data.frame()


##>    ID lab       date event episode  flag
##> 1   1 0.9 2006-08-15 FALSE       1  TRUE
##> 2   1 1.2 2006-08-18 FALSE       1  TRUE
##> 3   1 1.4 2006-08-20  TRUE       1  TRUE
##> 4   1 1.0 2006-08-22 FALSE       1  TRUE
##> 5   1 1.0 2006-08-26 FALSE       2 FALSE
##> 6   2 1.4 2015-05-04 FALSE       1 FALSE
##> 7   2 1.6 2015-07-14 FALSE       2 FALSE
##> 8   2 1.9 2015-07-17 FALSE       2 FALSE
##> 9   2 1.5 2015-08-01 FALSE       3 FALSE
##> 10  2 1.4 2016-09-21 FALSE       4 FALSE
##> 11  2 1.4 2016-09-26 FALSE       4 FALSE
##> 12  2 1.6 2016-10-17 FALSE       5 FALSE
##> 13  2 1.8 2016-10-19 FALSE       5 FALSE
##> 14  2 1.5 2016-10-22 FALSE       5 FALSE
##> 15  2 1.3 2017-01-06 FALSE       6 FALSE
##> 16  2 1.3 2017-02-28 FALSE       7 FALSE
##> 17  3 1.0 2018-12-06 FALSE       1 FALSE
##> 18  3 1.0 2019-05-17 FALSE       2 FALSE
##> 19  3 1.7 2019-09-19  TRUE       3  TRUE
##> 20  3 1.4 2019-09-23 FALSE       3  TRUE
##> 21  3 1.4 2020-01-17 FALSE       4 FALSE
##> 22  3 1.6 2021-01-08  TRUE       5  TRUE
```